# why I can't get map in admin? (geodjango)

Tags: django, geodjango

I am beginner for geodjango. I followed video tutorials on youtube. And I finished the geo-database installation.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as geomodels

class City(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    geometry = geomodels.PointField()
    class Meta:
        # order of drop-down list items
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name_plural = 'cities'
```

When I opened the admin page. There is only a dark image for the PointField.
[dark image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1OuE.png)
but I can add the location.
[location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4BC5.png)
How can I get the real map instead of a dark image?
I use Django 2.0 and python 3.6

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Oh, i ran into this problem once. And when i realize what is a problem i feel really stupid. Did you try to ***zoom out*** your dark image? It is a very **zoomed in** ocean :) Just zoom out and you will be able to see whole earth map. You can change default zoom by adding `default_zoom = value`(default is `4`) to your `ModelAdmin`.